# Do I use storyboards right?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

Am I using storyboards right?

I have several storyboards with view controllers in them.

---

When I need to navigate between them, I do the following:

I do create a new instance of the storyboard `let storyboard = ...` every time I use them. Is this a bad method? Or Should I declare it in the `view did load`?

```
func detailsRequestedForMessage(message: message) {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Additional", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MessageDetailsViewController") as! MessageDetailsViewController

        viewController.messageId = message.id
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }

func viewAllMessage() {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Additional", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AllMessageViewController") as! AllMessageViewController

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }

func viewOptions() {

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Options", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "OptionsViewController") as! OptionsViewController

        self.present(viewController, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: This is kind of an opinionated question, which is not what SO is about. That said, Storyboards really should *only* be used with IB (InterfaceBuilder). If your view controllers reside in a NIB, or are something you can simply instantiate in code, why not bypass instantiating a Storyboard object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It costs nothing to store a storyboard reference, but takes time to resolve a storyboard reference from a name. So I would say that you should put lines like

```
self.storyboardAdditional = UIStoryboard(name: "Additional", bundle: nil)
```

in `viewDidLoad`, storing the references in properties, and thereafter refer to the storyboards by way of the properties.

Comment: However please note that storyboards have a feature that allows a push or present segue to jump into a different storyboard. So why not use that feature instead of using code to push or present manually as you are doing?